# Determine if string has at least 2 same elements from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, function

I want to determine if string has at least 2 same elements from the array

```js
const array = ["!", "?"];

const string1 = "!hello"; // should return false
const string2 = "!hello?"; // should return false
const string3 = "!hello!"; // should return true
const string4 = "hello ??"; // should return true
const string5 = "hello ?test? foo"; // should return true
const string6 = "hello ?test ?? foo"; // should return true
```

I'm not sure what is gonna be better: a regex or a function? Any would be fine.

I tried this:

```js
const array = ["!", "?"];
const string = "test!";

array.every(ar => !string.includes(ar));
```

But it only detects if there at least 1 elements from array, not 2.

Comment: Would there only two elements in the array to match, or could there be three or more as well?

Comment: Could be more as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to do it:

```js
const check=(array,string)=>array.some(char=>(string.split(char).length-1)>=2)

const array = ["!", "?"];

console.log(check(array,"!hello"))
console.log(check(array,"!hello?"))
console.log(check(array,"!hello!"))
console.log(check(array,"hello ??"))
console.log(check(array,"hello ?test? foo"))
console.log(check(array, "hello ?test ?? foo"))
```

How does it work?

Let's split up (I mean to `split()` up)!

```js
const check=(array,string)=>
  array.some(char=>
    (
      string.split(char)
      .length-1
    )>=2
  )
```

- First, use `Array#some`, which tests that at least one element of the array should pass (i.e. either `?` or `!`)
- Split up the string by `char`, and count how many parts do we have

  - If we have `n` parts, it means that we have `n-1` places where the `char` matches. (e.g. 2 `|` splits a string into 3 parts: `a|b|c`)
- Finally, test whether we have 2 or more delimiters

Comment: best answer so far, easy to understand and pretty short!

Comment: couldn't do it, since you have to wait certain time before accepting correct answer :-)

Comment: tried to accept your question couple mins ago, it's around 15-20 mins from moment when question asked I think

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use a pattern with a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and a dynamically created [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for `[!?]` and a backreference `\1` to what is captured in group 1 to make sure there are 2 of the same characters present.

```
([!?]).*\1
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SCcQYZ/1)

For example

```js
const array = ["!", "?"];
const regex = new RegExp("([" + array.join(("")) + "]).*\\1");
[
  "!hello",
  "!hello?",
  "!hello!",
  "hello ??",
  "hello ?test? foo",
  "hello ?test ?? foo"
].forEach(str => console.log(str + ": " + regex.test(str)));
```

Comment: This works, *unless* the array contain a metacharacter, e.g. \ , `]`, `^`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string `split` and array `length` like:

```
const array = ["!", "?"];
const string6 = "hello ?test ?? foo"; 
var len1 = string6.split(array[0]).length;
var len2 = string6.split(array[1]).length;

if (len>2)||(len2>2)
 return true;
```

**EDIT**:  Using for loop

```
for (let i=0;i<array.length;i++){
 var len = string6.split(array[i]).length;
 if (len>2)
  return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: makes sense but what if array contains more elements? will be a lot of repetitive code

Answer (score 1):

You can follow a very simple solution like below. Split the string using the character in array. check the left of the split operation. If the length is minimum 2, then return true, else false.

Here is a sample jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sagarag05/qk8f2Lz7/

```
const array = ["!", "?"];
var str = "How are you!! doing !today?";

function isFound(arr, str){
  var isPresent = false;
  for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
      var res = str.split(arr[i]);
      if(res.length-1 >= 2){
          isPresent = true;
          break;
      }
  }
  return isPresent;
}
isFound(array, str);
```

Comment: This works, but the OP mentioned that the array doesn't necessarily contain exactly 2 elements...

Comment: That is still fine, this code was to just give you the logic. This can be modified using a for loop. Can you share what all characters are present in your array ?

Comment: I know how to do it, and just notified you, to help you make your answer better

Comment: I just modified my code, so if the array has more than 2 elements/characters, then also it will work. See the modified logic above.

Answer (score 0):

Use loop over array and count occurrence then check if occurrence is greater than 1.

```js
function has2(string1, array)
{
    for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        if (string1.split('').reduce(function(n, val) {
                return n + (val === array[i]);
            }, 0) > 1) 
        {
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(has2("!hello!", ["!", "?"])); // true
console.log(has2("!hello?", ["!", "?"])); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex trick approach.  We can try removing all characters from the input which are *not* part of the character class of characters to find.  Then, assert that there are at least two distinct characters remaining in the input.

```js
var input = "!hello?";
input = input.replace(/[^!?]+/g, "");
if (/(.).*(?!\1)./.test(input)) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
else {
    console.log("NO MATCH");
}
```

The logic here is fairly straightforward.  Using the input `!hello?` as an example, we first remove all non marker characters, leaving us with `!?`.  Then, we use a regex to assert that there are at least *two* distinct characters remaining.  This is true for this input, so we print `MATCH`.

**Edit:**

To build the regex alternation from your input array use `join`:

```
const array = ["!", "?"];
var regex = "[^" + array.join("") + "]+";
```

Comment: Yeah, tim's answer not correct, it's should *not* match "!hello?".

Comment: @Thefourthbird im pretty new to regex and got a question, can I use defined array inside regex string?

Comment: @Pleklo I made an update which shows you how to get from your input array to a regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function which can be handy for `n` number of occurrences to find

```
const arrayData = ["!", "?"];
const strData = "test!";

function checkElements(arr, str, occNum) {
   var ctr = 0;
   arr.forEach(function (elem) { if(str.includes(elem)) ctr++});

   return ctr >= occNum
}

checkElements(arrayData, strData, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution for this:

```
var a = ["!", "?"], s = "!hello!";
a.some(v=>s.split(v).length>2) // (returns true if multiples are found)
```

We can turn it into a function to test:

```
const a = ["!", "?"];
function Test(s) { return a.some(v => s.split(v).length > 2) }
const string1 = "!hello"; // should return false
const string2 = "!hello?"; // should return false
const string3 = "!hello!"; // should return true
const string4 = "hello ??"; // should return true
const string5 = "hello ?test? foo"; // should return true
const string6 = "hello ?test ?? foo"; // should return true

console.log(Test(string1), Test(string2), Test(string3), Test(string4), 
  Test(string5), Test(string6));

> false false true true true true
```

Note: My code changed a few times and in the end was close to the accepted answer and I didn't realize.  That said, you don't need to subtract anything, so that part is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkDups(arr, str) {
    var ctr = [];


    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var pos = str.indexOf(arr[i]);
        var count = 0;
        ctr[i] = 0;


        while (pos > -1) {
            ++count;
            pos = str.indexOf(arr[i], ++pos);
        }



        if (count >= 2) {
            return true
        }

    }


    return false
}

console.log(checkDups(["!", "?"], "!hello"))
console.log(checkDups(["!", "?"], "!hello?"))
console.log(checkDups(["!", "?"], "!hello!"))
console.log(checkDups(["!", "?"], "hello ??"))
console.log(checkDups(["!", "?"], "hello ?test? foo"))
console.log(checkDups(["!", "?"], "hello ?test ?? foo"))
```